Question about Android documentation: FileProviders
The documentation says:
It is possible to use FileProvider directly instead of extending it. However, this is not reliable and will causes crashes on some devices.

What are the reliability issues that can happen, and on which devices? How does one know they've side-stepped them successfully?

Here's what I was able to find out. Possibly, this is not the full story.
The original intent was that developers would define the FileProvider using only XML.

Add a <provider> element in the app manifest file.
Specify file provider paths in an XML file containing the <paths> element

In order to link the two elements you would use the <meta-data> element. Something like this:
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.mydomain.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_provider_paths"/>
</provider>

Later a problem was discovered:

Some OEMs strip meta-data from the manifest. This is problematic as
FileProvider was depending on meta-data to specify a resource
containing the paths that should be shared.

The solution was to allows FileProvider to be
extended in order to specify the resource id in code.
So, how do you know if you are OK? You should not see an IllegalArgumentException saying something like this:

Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority ...

